# RPM build fails on install section

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rpm, rpmbuild

I am trying to build my first rpm package, which is one simple executable (mysh).

My spec file:

```
Summary: bla <br>
Name: mysh <br>
Version: 1.0 <br>
Release: 1 <br>
Group: Applications <br>
Source: mysh-1.0.tar.gz <br>
URL: http://www.google.com <br>
Vendor: tadas sofware inc. <br>
Packager: tadas <br>
License: GPL 

%description <br>
a very good program!

%prep <br>
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_DIR/mysh-1.0 <br>
zcat $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/mysh-1.0.tar.gz | tar -xvf -

%build <br>
make 

%install <br>
cp mysh /usr/local/bin/mysh

%files <br>
/usr/local/bin/mysh
```

It fails with the following error:

```
cd: 8: can't cd to /home/tadzys/rpm/BUILDROOT/mysh-1.0-1.x86_64
```

Of course this file doesn't exist there. I've tried copying it there still there same error.  Not sure if my install section should put anything to BUILDROOT folder.

I am on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: You should not copy to /usr/ during %install%, the instalation path should be under %{buildroot}. Check http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#.25install_section

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you refer to directories in the target machine within the `%install` section, you need to reference everything relative to `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` (or `%{buildroot}`):

```
%install
cp mysh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/mysh
```

The `%files` section does **not** need to be updated, however.

Also, you should consider using the `install` command when copying files around. It's similar to `cp`, but `install` allows you to set the permission bits for the target file:

```
%install
install -m 755 mysh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/mysh
```

Comment: but /usr/local/bin/ is an absolute path. And of course when add $RPM_BUILD_ROOT in front of it, it cannot find it either: install: cannot create regular file `/home/tadzys/rpm/BUILDROOT/mysh-1.0-1.x86_64/usr/local/bin/mysh': No such file or directory

Comment: Yes, this is because it's trying to move the file to a directory in your staging area which doesn't exist. You'll need to issue a command like `mkdir -p /usr/local/bin` which will create it in the RPM build directory but have no effect on the target machine, assuming that directory exists.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Ah! That helped :) BTW I've removed %files section as per your comment, but then it doesn't create an RPM: error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
/usr/local/bin/mysh. After I brought back %files section all is good. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Oh no, I meant to say that you didn't need to change the %files section at all to use the macro, but glad you reverted :)