# rpm build fails to make build root dir

Tags: deployment, centos, rpm

I am working on making an rpm for a small program used within our enterprise.  The %build section of the rpm process works.  I'm having trouble with the install section.  I've referenced [this article response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7375894/988207) and I believe I am properly referring to the target location with respect to %{_buildroot}.

The program I'm making is to be installed as a system service.  So, after the rpm actually is generated for this step, I've got to add the next step in my installation process which is to include the script that is installed to the init.d location and run that install.  One step at a time though.

The build errors are as follows (omitting everything but %install):

```
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.eUDaCK
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ '[' /home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64
++ dirname /home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64
+ cd o2arbitord-1.0
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ install -m 555 /home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILD/o2arbitord-1.0/o2arbitord /home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64/usr/sbin
install: cannot create regular file `/home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64/usr/sbin': No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.eUDaCK (%install)
```

Now, my rpmbuild directory does not have the directory `/home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64/usr/sbin`.  While I know that's part of the problem, the rpmbuild process isn't making the directory `/home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64` either.  What I don't understand about that one is: why?  Looking at the script output above you can clearly see the line: `mkdir /home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64`.  So, why isn't the directory made?

How does the line `BuildRoot:   %(mktemp -ud %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-XXXXXX)` from whatever the definition of %{_buildroot} is?  I thought that was the definition, but it appears to be something different.

For reference, my spec file

```
Name:       o2arbitord
Version:    1.0
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    a daemon

Group:      Applications/System
License:    GPL
URL:        http://My.site
Source0:    %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRoot:  %(mktemp -ud %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-XXXXXX)
BuildArch:  x86_64

BuildRequires:  libusb1-devel
#Requires:  

%description


%prep
%setup -q


%build
make -f o2arbitord.mk


%install
install -m 555 %{_builddir}/%{name}-%{version}/%{name} %{buildroot}%{_sbindir}

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}


%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/usr/sbin/o2arbitord

%changelog
```

Comment: You need to create the directory before you can install a file into it. `%{__mkdir_p} %{buildroot}%{_sbindir}` or `%{__install} -d %{buildroot}%{_sbindir}`

Comment: @EtanReisner thank you.  I didn't know of those two macros/whatever.  I tried to make the directory in the %prep section but that failed.  I placed the first of your two suggestions in %install and, of course, it worked.  Too bad I can't accept a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to install a file into a directory that doesn't exist (yet).

RPM only creates the `%{buildroot}` for you automatically. Anything under that you need to create yourself.

So when you run

```
install -m 555 %{_builddir}/%{name}-%{version}/%{name} %{buildroot}%{_sbindir}
```

where `%{buildroot}%{_sbindir}` expands to `/home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64/usr/sbin` RPM has only created `/home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64` for you already.

You need to create the `/usr/sbin` part of that path and then copy the file into it.

You can do that with either

```
%{__mkdir_p} '%{buildroot}%{_sbindir}'
```

or

```
%{__install} -d '%{buildroot}%{_sbindir}'
```

Where

```
$ rpm -E '__mkdir_p = %{__mkdir_p}'
__mkdir_p = /bin/mkdir -p
$ rpm -E '__install = %{__install}'
__install = /usr/bin/install
```

Comment: That was the strange thing.  I know I saw that the process had made `/home/packager/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/o2arbitord-1.0-1.el6.x86_64`.  Yet that directory didn't exist.  Adding the first line you mention here made every directory I needed (of course).  Thanks much.

Comment: That directory didn't exist when? RPM cleans up for you from failed builds. It should have existed during the build and likely did not once the build failed. Also on CentOS 6 you don't need to manually set `BuildRoot` and generally should not (you can set _buildrootdir if you want to control the general location though).